# What is the difference between CBC and CBC3 cipher suites?

Tags: tls, openssl, cipher-selection

Consider below  cipher suite TLS v1.0

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                **DES-CBC-SHA**
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA           **DES-CBC3-SHA**
```

Wwhat is the meaning of CBC and CBC3, and what is the difference between them?

Comment: Therefore one should avoid using both: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA        
 and TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 4):

DES-CBC-SHA is [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) encryption, SHA-1 as HMAC.
DES-CBC3-SHA is [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) encryption, SHA-1 as HMAC.

Comment: And (as said in the dupe) only OpenSSL. and apps/libraries built on top of OpenSSL, uses these names instead of the standard ones.